# React Native FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Could not resolve ':classpath'. Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1

Tags: android, react-native, classpath, gradle-3.0

When I make the command "react-native run-android" then it happened:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'AsomeProject'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle                                                               -3.0.1.pom
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle                                                               -3.0.1.jar

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Is your network behind a proxy?

Comment: no. is that something for IDM?

Comment: Duplicate question. Refer the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52944598/could-not-find-aapt2-proto-jar/52945215#52945215)

Answer (score 28):

I had the same problem, I tried [Manoj Prabhakar's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47459076/3172725) but I fixed adding the `google()` repository to the buildscript block in the project level `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
```

Comment: this solved the issue for me...thank you Roberto Martucci

Answer (score 8):

I added `google()` and `mavenlocal()` to the `buildscript`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: should it be `mavenCentral()` ?

Answer (score 6):

Jcenter does not have Gradle 3.0.1.

[image: Gradle 3.0.1]

It is available in Google's maven repository. [here](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html)

You should add google() to allprojects in your project level build.gradle

**Do this:**

In your react native project, Navigate to -> android -> build.gradle.

add google() to allproject repository like this:

[image]

This should fix your problem.

**Edit 1:**
replace google() with this

```
maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com/"
}
```

Comment: should i do it for every new project?

Comment: same problem as before

Answer (score 1):

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should give more context to an answer rather than just dropping a block of code that the OP or future readers may not understand.

Comment: sorry just started , many times tried to change, but I don't know not working

Answer (score 1):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google() // I had to put this before jcenter(). If I put jcenter() first it fails when running react-native run-android
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

To be clear though, if i put `jcenter()` first in buildscript, I could still get a successful build within Android Studio. Running `react-native` run-android however was failing until I put `google()` in front of `jcenter()`. After that everything was smooth as butter.

Answer (score 0):

So,for me this fixed problem,add google() to repositories

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
  }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
  }
}
```

then from terminal navigate to your project and run

```
 cd android && gradlew clean
```

then inside your project run

```
 react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing the class path in your build.gradle file from

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
```

to

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```