# Could not find aapt2-proto.jar

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, jcenter, aapt2

See this [link](https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/0.3.1/) (as I suspected) has the POM file and no jar.

Important Notes:

- I am using [latest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native) version of react native ... v0.57.3 and also [latest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cli) version of react-native-cli ... v2.0.1 at this time.
- I have Java 11 installed in my computer.
- I am using [latest](https://gradle.org/releases/) gradle release at this time ... v4.10.2
- I am using Mac OSX Mojave

The distribution url is:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
```

Here is the error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'AwesomePlacesApp'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find aapt2-proto.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:0.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/0.3.1/aapt2-proto-0.3.1.jar
```

Comment: Did you try any upgrades in your project?

Comment: Which type of upgrades @KosalramRamaKrishnan ? ... FWIW, I just edited my comment that I am using latest version of react native and react native cli ... Its a fresh project ...

Comment: Got the same error. If you follow the link you get a 404. I guess we have to wait until it is resolved by jcenter.

Comment: @Harry I doubt that you might be using incompatible SDK versions. Missing jar files usually happens a lot.
Just open your project in Android Studio and it will build your project freshly based on your newer versions whatever you've used in your project. Let me know if the issue persists.

Comment: Hey @KosalramRamaKrishnan android studio is already opened and seems like its a fresh build also ... see this image screenshot https://i.imgur.com/YY4UMzh.png ... Am I missing something sir?

Comment: Like this @jstrater (see image screenshot) ?? https://i.imgur.com/0W1XcZa.png ... After `jcenter()` function execution sir?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52944600/4255978

Comment: @M.Ricciuti It's actually a duplicate. Even I shared the same link. Thanks, Harry I learned a new thing.

Comment: Thanks all of you guys ... I just successfully build it ... Thanks a lot ... Even I learned a new thing today ;)

Comment: Food for Thought @KosalramRamaKrishnan ... Though it works, but would like to confirm, Is this the correct code that I have changed https://i.imgur.com/t795JWr.png or am I missing something

Comment: duplicate with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52979557/8034839

Answer (score 49):

It seems like AAPT2(Android Asset Packaging Tool 2) is available in Google's maven repository.

You need to include **google()** under repositories in build.gradle file as shown:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      google() // here
      jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha12'
  }
} 
allprojects {
  repositories {
      google() // and here
      jcenter()
}
```

Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279792/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildaapt23-2-0) for more in detail.

Note: Order also matters, if jcenter() is above google() it fails.

Comment: Note that the order matters, if jcenter() is above google() it failed for me.

Comment: If it isn't working for you, make sure you change both locations. Also take @fejd's advice.

Comment: Indeed, place google() as the first item in repositiories

Comment: @PedroPauloAmorim it's not working for me too. do you find any other answer?

Answer (score 15):

This seems to be a jCenter issue. Until the issue is fixed you can temporarily change Android Gradle Plugin version to `3.1.0` within root `build.gradle` file:

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        // other imports here...
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I changed the order of this file: *android/build.gradle*

For me is working with this order:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
    }
    repositories {
        google()        
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
          url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }        
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This question's answer In build.gradle change position of google() and place it first:
This is how it was before, if you don't have google() add it as the first one in the buildscript:

```
buildscript {
       repositories {
                  jcenter()
                  google()
}
```

change to,

```
buildscript {
       repositories {
               google()
               jcenter()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Project -> Open Module Setting -> "Project Structure - Project"

Check your **Android Plugin Repository** and **Default Library Repository**.

Note: google(), jcenter - its default value in my project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add google() to repositories in build.gradle file and put it at **first position**:

```
...
repositories {
    google()        
    jcenter()
}
...
```

In my case the problem was the repository order.

Answer (score 0):

For me problem fixed just after gradle update, note that I had problem even with adding google() to repository