# AAPT: error: resource string not found react native

Tags: react-native, android-resources

I am trying to build a react native app with facebook login.

As facebook suggests I have created two resources string `string/facebook_app_id` and `string/fb_login_protocol_scheme` and include it in Manifest file.

But when I try to build app I get these errors

```
 AAPT: error: resource string/facebook_app_id (aka package.name:string/facebook_app_id) not found.
 AAPT: error: resource string/fb_login_protocol_scheme (aka package.name:string/fb_login_protocol_scheme) not found.
```

Comment: did you upgrade your gradle version recently?

Comment: If you have upgraded to latest gradle version you might encounter problems like missing AAPT jar. Please take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52944598/could-not-find-aapt2-proto-jar/52945215#52945215)

Comment: @KosalramRamaKrishnan I followed but no success.

Comment: Have you added strings in res/values/string.xml? Also, have you mentioned the package name properly, that will use those strings, in Manifest file?